# optimum slice size for backing up data to DVD

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, backup, dvd

How big should a slice be for a DVD, assuming that [the file system restricts the size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#The_2.2F4_GiB_file_size_limit)?

Referencing:

http://ubuntu.5.n6.nabble.com/DVD-file-size-td4572772.html

should slices be 1GB or so?  What's an efficient slice size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_9660&oldid=502651980#The_2.2F4_GiB_file_size_limit),

> It is, however, possible to circumvent this limitation by using the multi-extent (fragmentation) feature of ISO 9660 Level 3 and create ISO 9660 filesystems and single files up to 8 TB. With this, files larger than 4 GB can be split up into multiple extents (sequential series of sectors), each not exceeding the 4 GB limit. For example, the free software such as InfraRecorder and mkisofs as well as Roxio Toast are able to create ISO 9660 filesystems that use multi-extent files to store files larger than 4 GB on appropriate media such as recordable DVDs.

So a slice can be as large as a DVD (about 4.3 GB binary for a single-layer disc).

## Limited file size

If, for whatever reason, you need to limit the file size to no more than *max_file_size* and the disk holds *disk_size*, make your slice size the largest *disk_size* / *s* less than *max_file_size*, where *s* is an integer. That way, you can fit *s* slices on the disk exactly (ignoring round-off error), wasting no space. For *disk_size* ≈ 4.3 GB and *max_file_size* = 1 GB, you could then make each slice 880 MB, fitting 5 slices per disc.

Comment: pardon, I meant to state **assuming** that the file system prevents large files, what's the optimum slice size?

Comment: @Thufir: Okay. Edited.

Comment: I haven't tried that, so I've accepted the answer assuming your arithmetic is correct :)